# Configure Auth0 Extensions with Terraform

Tags: terraform, auth0

I have configured my current infrastructure in terraform. Since I am using Auth0, I would also like to script this via Terraform. Hashicorp does not provide its own provider for Auth0, but a community provider entry does exist [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/type/community-index.html) that points to [here](https://github.com/alexkappa/terraform-provider-auth0). I saw that you can create APIs, scopes, etc. However, I see no way to activate or configure Auth0 extensions. Isn't this part of the plugin? If not, are there alternatives to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You might consider opening an issue on the GitHub repo you referenced. They will be able to provide more specific answers.

Comment: Hey there! I'm Konrad and I'm a community engineer at Auth0. Yep the repo you referenced was developed by one of our community members and not by Auth0 employees however we are working on getting an official SDK for Terraform. Don't have the ETA on that yet but if you want to be the first to hear about that make sure to visit our community forum regularly. It's here: https://community.auth0.com/. I guess it should be there any time soon!